# filter a list of dictionary based on two keys

Tags: python, dictionary

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    list_of_dicts = [{k:v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

Hello,I have csv file which I make to a list of dictionaries,I want to filter its output on ASIN (remove duplicate if found)based on "Merchant 1 Price" I want to get the lower price, not all of them have duplicates i.e remove duplicates (keep the one with the lowest merchant 1 price),and keep the non duplicates (in a new list), here is a sample of list

```
{'Product Name': 'NFL Buffalo Bills Bedding Set, Twin', 'Amazon Price': '84.99', 'ASIN': 'B004B3M5UU', 'Merchant_1': 'Homedepot', 'Merchant_1_Price': '72.65', 'Merchant_1_Stock': 'False', 'Merchant_1_Link': 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/Jaguars-2-PIECE-Draft-Multi-Twin-Comforter-Set-1NFL862000014RET/303181069', 'Amazon Image': '=IMAGE("{temp}",4,100,100)', 'Merchant_1_Image': '=IMAGE("{temp}",4,100,100)'}
{'Product Name': 'NFL Buffalo Bills Bedding Set, Twin', 'Amazon Price': '84.99', 'ASIN': 'B004B3M5UU', 'Merchant_1': 'Overstock', 'Merchant_1_Price': '61.64', 'Merchant_1_Stock': 'False', 'Merchant_1_Link': 'https://www.overstock.com/Bedding-Bath/The-Northwest-Company-NFL-Buffalo-Bills-Draft-Twin-2-piece-Comforter-Set/13330480/product.html', 'Amazon Image': '=IMAGE("{temp}",4,100,100)', 'Merchant_1_Image': '=IMAGE("{temp}",4,100,100)'}
{'Product Name': 'EGO Power+ HT2400 24-Inch 56-Volt Lithium-ion Cordless Hedge Trimmer - Battery and Charger Not Included', 'Amazon Price': '129.0', 'ASIN': 'B00N0A4S1O', 'Merchant_1': 'Homedepot', 'Merchant_1_Price': '129.00', 'Merchant_1_Stock': 'True', 'Merchant_1_Link': 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/EGO-24-in-56-Volt-Lithium-Ion-Cordless-Hedge-Trimmer-Battery-and-Charger-Not-Included-HT2400/205163108', 'Amazon Image': '=IMAGE("{temp}",4,100,100)', 'Merchant_1_Image': '=IMAGE("{temp}",4,100,100)'}
```

I tried plenty of two for loops but I can't seem to find the correct code logic.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm perplexed by the list and dict comprehension in your current code. Are either of them actually changing anything you get from `csv.DictReader`? It seems like you may just want `list_of_dicts = list(csv.DictReader(...)`. No need for either of the comprehensions. Unless that's where you're trying to wedge in your filtering (which seems tricky).

Comment: @Blckknght what is a better way to read from file?

Comment: Like I said in the previous comment, just call `list` on the `DictReader` object you create, if you want to turn it into a list right away. You don't need a list and dict comprehension if they don't change anything (that's just an inconvenient way of deep copying, which isn't needed here). You could also defer consuming the `DictReader` until you iterate over the dictionaries (e.g. for the filtering), as long as you don't mind keeping the file open a little longer. If you don't need the unfiltered list for anything, there's no need for it to exist at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deduplicate your list of dicts is to build a dictionary keyed by the unique field, which in this case is `'ASIN'`. When you find a duplicate, you can select the one with the lower `'Merchant_1_Price'` field:

```
by_asin = {}
for item in list_of_dicts:
    asin = item['ASIN']
    if (
        asin not in by_asin or
        float(item['Merchant_1_Price']) < float(by_asin[asin]['Merchant_1_Price'])
    ):
        by_asin[asin] = item

deduplicated_list_of_dicts = list(by_asin.values())
```

In the loop, we're first extracting the `asin` from the current item since we're going to use it several times. Then we check if that ASIN is either not yet in the `by_asin` dictionary, or if it is in there, we check if the price on the new item is lower than the price of the old item. In either of those cases, we put the new item into the `by_asin` dictionary (replacing the previous value, if there was one).

Comment: can you explain a bit of what is going on in for loop please

Comment: I've updated to add a paragraph explaining the code. I did also the comparison of prices to use a numerical comparison, rather than just comparing the strings with the prices in them (because you probably expect a cost of `'9.99'` to be less than `'10.00'`). If you're going to deal with those prices more, you might want to convert them in the dictionary to some numeric type, and `decimal.Decimal` is probably better in the general case than `float` (which is probably good enough for the comparisons here).