# Replacing values in a dictionary when there is a higher value for a given key later in file?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm a fairly new coder and having trouble with this problem - forgive me if any of my vocab is off.  I have a tab delimited text file with multiple columns, as below.

```
Cat    2   32
Dog    5   56
Bird    10  234
Dog  2   23
Alligator    2   94
Cat  10  34
Tiger    2   973
Bird    2   355
```

I want to use the first column as a key, and the second as a value.  If there is a repeat of a key, I want the dictionary to store the highest value in the text file.  For instance, I would want `Cat:10` and `Dog:5` as `key:value` pairs.

I have opened the file and created a dictionary which takes the first column as the key and second as a value.  I have updated based on Shizzen83's super helpful advice to:

```py
animals = '/path/animals.txt'
file = open(animals, mode='r')

top_scores = dict()
for line in file :
    goodline = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    data = goodline.split("\t")
    top_scores[data[0]] = max(top_scores.setdefault(data[0], data[1]), data[1])

print(top_scores)
```

The output then becomes:

```
{'Alligator': '2', 'Tiger': '2', 'Bird': '2', 'Dog': '5', 'Cat': '2'}
```

The desired output, however is:

```
{'Alligator': '2', 'Tiger': '2', 'Bird': '10', 'Dog': '5', 'Cat': '10'}
```

Any help to make it save the highest value in the file for a given key would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "This won't run" is not specific enough. Are you getting errors? If so, post the exact traceback. Are you getting unexpected output? If so, please specify what output you're expecting and how it differs from what you're actually getting. Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't see where `value` is defined before your conditional statement, so that may be a source of error.

Comment: Unrelated to the dictionary creation, but you should look into context managers and using `with` statements for file I/O.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57046531/filter-a-list-of-dictionary-based-on-two-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take advantage of the `setdefault` method of dictionary class, it gets the value associated to a key, and if the key is not found, set a default value. By the way, you don't have to check yourself if the key is present.

```
animals = '/path/animals.txt'
file = open(animals, mode='r')

top_scores = dict()
for line in file :
    goodline = line.rstrip('\r\n')
    data = goodline.split("\t")
    top_scores[data[0]] = max(top_scores.setdefault(data[0], int(data[1])), int(data[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've added an edit with these changes, if you have any ideas

Comment: @ALR presumably you want to use int values, so sth like `top_scores[data[0]] = max(top_scores.setdefault(data[0], int(data[1])), int(data[1]))` in the dict and for comparison

Comment: Shizzen83 and @StephanSchlecht thanks so much! This works great.